# Transform raw data in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have raw data in a specific format and I want to transform it into some other format. I tried using Index-Match function, it's working for **Revenue** but not for **Profit**. For ex: - Revenue of "ABC" in "01-2023" is **100** and Profit is **50** but when I run Index-Match, it's giving Profit as **100** because **"Match"** value for **01-2023** is 2. Can someone please help me with this?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Normally you should tag spreadsheet questions as either google-sheets or excel, not both - can you clarify which one you are looking for please?

Comment: Can you post the formula(s) that you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

### Unpivot (Excel Formula)

```
=LET(Data,A2:G6,
    dRows,ROWS(Data)-1,dCols,(COLUMNS(Data)-1)/2,Cells,dRows*dCols,
    rSeq,MOD(SEQUENCE(Cells,,0),dRows)+1,vSeq,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(Cells)/dRows,0),
    rd,INDEX(DROP(TAKE(Data,,1),1),rSeq),hd,INDEX(TOCOL(DROP(TAKE(Data,1),,dCols+1)),vSeq),
    vData,DROP(DROP(Data,1),,1),rev,TOCOL(TAKE(vData,,dCols)),pro,TOCOL(TAKE(vData,,-dCols)),
HSTACK(rd,hd,rev,pro))
```